# Peewee - how to update only one record within for loop?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I try to update **line** record within for loop. Unfortunetely - .update executes action for all records in the table - not only for current line record. What is wrong?

```
    with db.atomic():
        lines = list(Line.select().where(Line.document_no == counter+5000))
        entries = []
        for line in lines:
            entries.append(Entry(posting_date=dtime.today(), item_no=line.item_no, quantity=line.ordered_quantity))
            line.update(quantity=line.ordered_quantity, received = True).execute()
        Entry.bulk_create(entries)
```

I expect updating only one line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instead filter to ensure that only one item is updated:

```
with db.atomic():
    lines = list(Line.select().where(Line.document_no == counter+5000))
    entries = []
    for line in lines:
        entries.append(...)
        Line.update(
            quantity=line.ordered_quantity,
            received=True
        ).where(Line.id == line.id).execute()
    Entry.bulk_create(entries)
```

Or you can simply do:

```
with db.atomic():
    lines = list(Line.select().where(Line.document_no == counter+5000))
    entries = []
    for line in lines:
        entries.append(...)
        line.quantity = line.ordered_quantity
        line.received = True
        line.save()

    Entry.bulk_create(entries)
```